# Executing sp in ssms much faster than executing in job step

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-agent

My stored procedure takes 23 secs in ssms but takes 4 minutes when exec via job.  Can you please help me in finding out. Below is SP code

```
ALTER procedure  [ops].[trailers_sitting_builder_mod]
--WITH RECOMPILE
as

SET NOCOUNT ON;

INSERT INTO [ops].[trailers_sitting_mod]
           ([trailer_number]
           ,[division]
           ,[trailer_year]
           ,[trailer_make]
           ,[vin]
           ,[license_plate]
           ,[trailer_type]
           ,[trailer_status]
           ,[last_contact_customer]
           ,[last_contact_city]
           ,[last_contact_state]
           ,[last_contact_date]
           ,[last_gps_utc_datetime]
           ,[last_gps_mst_datetime]
           ,[last_gps_latitude]
           ,[last_gps_longitude]
           ,[last_gps_geotype]
           ,[last_gps_geoname]
           ,[last_gps_state]
           ,[last_gps_country]
           ,[last_gps_point_distance]
           ,[last_gps_point_direction]
           ,[last_gps_area]
           ,[last_gps_area_planner]
           ,[last_battery_status]
           ,[idle_duration_days]
           ,[idle_exception]
           ,[gps_not_reporting]
           ,[icc_gps_difference]
           ,[report_last_ran])

SELECT
            ltrim(rtrim(tm.TRTRLR)),
            tm.TRDV#,
            tm.TRYEAR,
            tm.TRMAKE,
            tm.TRSER,
            tm.TRMNPR,
            tm.TRTYPE,
            tm.TRTRST,
            tm.TRCUST,
            c.city_name,
            tm.TRCST,
            dd.Date_Value,
            mt.last_gps_datetime,
            dateadd(hh, -7, mt.last_gps_datetime),
            sb.sb_latitude,
            sb.sb_longitude,
            sb.sb_geotypename,
            sb.sb_geoname,
            sb.sb_state,
            sb.sb_country,
            sb.sb_distance,
            sb.sb_direction,
            sb.sb_areanum,
            p.planner_name,
            sb.sb_battery,
            sb.sb_idleduration,
            case
                when 
                    mt.last_gps_datetime is null or
                    datediff(dd, mt.last_gps_datetime, getdate()) > 7 or
                    sb.sb_idleduration > 7
                then 1
                else 0
            end, --as idle_exception,
            case
                when
                    mt.last_gps_datetime is null or
                    datediff(dd, mt.last_gps_datetime, getdate()) > 7
                then 1
                else 0
            end, --as gps_not_reporting,
            case
                when 
                    sb.sb_state <> tm.TRCST and
                    mt.last_gps_datetime is not null and
                    datediff(dd, mt.last_gps_datetime, getdate()) <= 7
                then 1
                else 0
            end, --as icc_gps_difference,
            getdate() as report_last_ran
        from
            MVT520.MVT520.IESSHARE.TRAILERS tm
        left join (
            select
                date_value,
                julian_day
            from
                BIWHSReports.dw_pub.dbo.tbl_Dim_Date 
        ) dd on tm.TRCDAT = dd.Julian_Day
        left join (
            select
                city_code,
                state,
                city_name
            from
                BIWHSReports.dw_pub.ops.tbl_Dim_ICC_city
            where
                etl_current_row = 1
        ) c on tm.TRCCTY = c.city_code and tm.TRCST = c.state
        left join (
            select
                sb_assetid,
                max(sb_time) as last_gps_datetime
            from
                BIWHSReports.DS_Raw.ops3rdParty.tblSkyBitz
            group by
                sb_assetid
        ) mt on ltrim(rtrim(tm.TRTRLR)) = mt.sb_assetid
        left join BIWHSReports.DS_Raw.ops3rdParty.tblSkyBitz sb on mt.sb_assetid = sb.sb_assetid and mt.last_gps_datetime = sb.sb_time
        left join (
            select
                area_code,
                planner_name
            from
                BIWHSReports.dw_pub.ops.tbl_dim_icc_area
            where
                etl_current_row = 1
        ) p on sb.sb_areanum = p.area_code
        where TRDLT <> 'D'
        --OPTION (RECOMPILE)

GO

--EXEC ops.trailers_sitting_builder
```

Comment: Just a guess, but session options are different which causes different plan to be used? Does it behave the same way with the option recompile?

Comment: We'd need to see the plans in both cases to know how to help you with this one.

Comment: Some other details are necessary too. What is your sample size? Is this 4 minutes in the job *every time*, and 23 seconds in SSMS *every time*, or did you run it once each? Is it possible that the job ran first, and it took longer because the data had to be read off disk, the plan had to be compiled, etc.? The run from SSMS was faster because the plan was already compiled, the data was already in cache thanks to the job? Did both the job and SSMS run affect the exact same number of rows? Were they operating under the same concurrency? Did you check for blocking?

Comment: Sample size - Ran from SSMS 10 times (23-30 secs), run from job 10 times (3:35-4:00 minutes) No blocking is observed (using SQL Sentry) running SP either from SSMS or Job.  Captured job plan using SQL profiler.  Looking at plans and wondering why the huge difference in estimated row size for job sp execution plan to another. Plans are in my dropbox -http://bit.ly/1HbGmYb

Comment: Both insert the exact number of rows 4770.  Trying to figure out why plan from profiler only shows estimates

Comment: OPTION RECOMPILE had no appreciable effect on speed

Comment: Another clue,  Why would the queryplanhash's be different but the queryhash's the same when the sp is executed from SSMS vs SQL Agent Job? Note: both are RetrievedfromCache = "True"

Comment: Edited job step so Session Options would be the same as when run in SSMS

Comment: Both have an Eager Spool operator. SSMS execution has 5188 rows  but when run from Job row estimate is 8 million rows!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many of the plan options in Profiler are estimated plans, so you will have to use the correct one to get the actual plan. Since you are using SQL Sentry (great product by the way :) ), you should be able to get the plan for the statement run from the Top SQL tab if you check shortly after the job was run.

Regardless, IF at all possible, I recommend that rather than doing the cross server query within the main query that you pull that data into a temp table first (assuming that it isn't a ton of rows), so that the optimizer has an "easier" time of generating an accurate plan. Additionally, the query you shared is relatively complex. I realize that there are far worse out there, but one goal I always keep in mind is to not make the optimizer do too much. So, the "KISS" (Keep It Simple Stupid) methodology can often be helpful when applied to writing our queries. Help the optimizer and you help yourself. With that in mind, I might recommend that you eliminate the subqueries in the joins and make those temp tables too, again assuming that you aren't looking at a ton of rows. As with everything in performance tuning, try, test, repeat, until you get a solid plan that is going to work well in every situation.

One final note here, it would be good to read this article from Joe Sack - http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/joe/distributed-query-plan-quality-and-sql-server-2012-sp1/. I'm not sure what version you are running, but there may be some issues there as well.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Well, many thanks James, Mark, Aaron and especially David Benoit.  I read the Joe Sack article you mentioned and it led me to Benjamin Nevarez's article - http://www.benjaminnevarez.com/2011/05/optimizer-statistics-on-linked-servers/. which then pointed out the BOL - Guidelines for Using Distributed Queries.  The stored procedure had 3 remote queries.  The job with the Bad Plan ran (executed the SP) under the domain account configured for the SQL Agent.  This account had sufficient privileges for two of the linked servers (thus accurate row estimates in plan).  But for the remote query with the bad row estimates (8961230 rows) the linked server local login was mapped to a remote login that had neither DBO or DDL Admin on the remote database or sa on the remote server.  Once I corrected this, the job ran in 23 seconds which is about the same as executing the sp in SSMS.  Again Thanks Guys!